# How can I wrap grid elements on small screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive table with div elements.  However as the screen gets smaller I'd like to move cells 4 & 5 below the first 3 cells and make them stretch across the width of the screen

[image]

```
<div className="grid">
<div className="grid_row">
    <div className="grid_cell">
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div className="grid_cell">
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div className="grid_cell">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div className="grid_cell">
        <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div className="grid_cell">
        <p>5</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into the fundamentals of responsive layout, such as media queries? Your question is rather broad, but it's all been covered before. I'd start there.

Comment: Simply media queries are the correct answer.

Comment: Honestly, this is a job for flexbox,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... let's try.
You have to use media queries.
Here you can set rules for a specific screen resolution, or whatever you want.
For example, you can write one rule for tablets, one rule for mobile phones, and one rule for computers and so on.

```
.example {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .example {background: red;}
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .example {background: green;}
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .example {background: blue;}
} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .example {background: orange;}
} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .example {background: pink;}
}
```

I hope it was helpful, best regards,